# How to order django models according decimal points

Tags: python, django

I have created model where I am ordering by feature_req_no

Feature_req_no is in the form of:
1,
1.1,
1.1.1,
2,
2.1,
10,
10.1,
When I try to do Ordering using feature_req_no the ordering is as follows:
1,
10,
10.1,
1.1,
1.1.1,
2,
2.1

Expected output:
1,
1.1,
1.1.1,
2,
2.1,
10,
10.1

Comment: could you please share your model ?

Comment: What is the type of 'Feature_req_no' field? Is it DecimalField or CharField?

Comment: note that in django DecimalField is stored as a string.That is why you are getting that.

Comment: Type of Feature_req_no field is string. I am using CharField

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.